# Disable the Close (X) button in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to disable the Close button (the little X) for a script I wrote that has exit functionality that needs to be run (triggered via CTRL-C) and I want to remove the ability for users to bypass that by X'ing out of the window.

Answer (score 3):

```
Function _Disable-X {
    #Calling user32.dll methods for Windows and Menus
    $MethodsCall = '
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern long GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool EnableMenuItem(long hMenuItem, long wIDEnableItem, long wEnable);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern long SetWindowLongPtr(long hWnd, long nIndex, long dwNewLong);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool EnableWindow(long hWnd, int bEnable);
    '

    $SC_CLOSE = 0xF060
    $MF_DISABLED = 0x00000002L


    #Create a new namespace for the Methods to be able to call them
    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodsCall -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32

    $PSWindow = Get-Process -Pid $PID
    $hwnd = $PSWindow.MainWindowHandle

    #Get System menu of windows handled
    $hMenu = [Win32.NativeMethods]::GetSystemMenu($hwnd, 0)

    #Disable X Button
    [Win32.NativeMethods]::EnableMenuItem($hMenu, $SC_CLOSE, $MF_DISABLED) | Out-Null
}

_Disable-X
```

Credit: https://www.makak.ch/disable-close-button-in-powershell-window/